# Проблема с finish()

Tags: android, java

Есть код:

```
public class Dialog2 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.exit)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, this)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, this)
                .setMessage(R.string.save_data);
        return adb.create();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                saveData();
                finish();
                break;
            case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                finish();
                break;
            case Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                break;
        }
    }

    void saveData() {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 2: onDismiss");
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 2: onCancel");
    }
}
```

Хочу закрывать приложение по нажатию кнопки, но ругается на finish(). Это потому, что он находится не в MainActivity? На что его можно заменить или изменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы не поверите, но снова  getActivity().finish();

Comment: :D
Спасибо. getActivity() - очень полезный метод.